# Run code when link is clicked, even if I stay on the same page

Tags: angularjs

I have a collapsible sidebar navigation, and any time users click a link on it, I have the sidebar hide automatically. I achieve this in the `run` method by using the following code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
        $rootScope.closeNavigation();
    })
});
```

Where `app` is my Angularjs module.

The problem is that it gets a little unintuitive to use, when you click a link in the navigation for the page you're already on, and then nothing happens. What I would like is to have the sidebar close anyway, so that the users still get focus on the content, even if it's the same content.

But Angularjs doesn't execute the `$routeChangeSucess` event, if there is no route change happening. So what can I use instead?

Comment: do it in controller of navigation...

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `ng-show = isPanelVisible` and `ng-click = closePanel()` on the html sidepanel tag (e.g. a `<div>`).

Then, define `$scope.closePanel()` in the controller associated to the actual view. For instance

```
 $scope.closePanel = function() {
     $scope.isPanelVisible = false;
 }
```

See an example [here](http://dpiccone.github.io/ng-pageslide/examples/). Code is [here](https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide/blob/master/examples/index.html). Note that it doesn't use `ng-show`, but the behaviour is the same.